# Image search browser with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to do an image search engine with Tkinter. Basically a "Pokedex" that searches for images inside a specific folder on my computer associated with a specific name.[Example of the image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r3NE.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob
import natsort
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")
window.title("CoreaninhaDex")
window.config(padx=10, pady=10)

title_label = tk.Label(window, text = 'CoreaninhaDex')
title_label.config(font=('Arial', 32))
title_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

target_image = tk.Label(window)
target_image.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

target_information = tk.Label(window)
target_information.config(font=("Arial", 20))
target_information.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

photos_names_list = ["target1","target2","target3","target4","target5"]
#FUNCTION
def showimage():

    dir1 = r"C:\Users\path"
    path1 = os.path.join(dir1, '*g')
    files = glob.glob(path1)
    files1 = natsort.natsorted(files, reverse=False)
    for x in files1:
        img = plt.imread(x)
        image = Image.open(img)
        imag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


    target_image.config(image=imag)
    target_image.image = imag




label_id_name = tk.Label(window, text="ID or Name")
label_id_name.config(font=("Arial", 20))
label_id_name.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

text_id_name = tk.Text(window, height = 1)
text_id_name.config(font=("Arial", 20))
text_id_name.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

btn_load = tk.Button(window, text="Load target", command = showimage)
btn_load.config(font=("Arial", 20))
btn_load.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

The output generates a display. But I can't associate the image with any name or even upload the images.

I would like help to write a showimage () function that would do this.